# Postman is opened instead of google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 , when I click on google chrome , Postman is opened instead of chrome !!

[image]

Comment: How do you try to open google-chrome? From the Dock?

Comment: By clicking on the icon in the launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

edit ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Icon=google-chrome
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id={gobbledigook}
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Google-chrome
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

remove `--app-id={gobbledigook}` from the Exec line, save, and then try again

Comment: How to save changes please ?

Comment: @hous Which TextEditor are you using?